# Какие контроллеры для страниц, использующих капчу, выбрать для подключения капчи? (Kohana Framework 3.2)

Tags: php, kohana, captcha

Необходимо вставить в контроллеры страниц `$captcha = Captcha::instance();` и в блок контента `$content->captcha = $captcha;` Куда конкретно в какие файлы в место вставить эти строчки кода?

Использую для подключения капчи вот эту инструкцию: http://kohanaframework.su/modules/captcha.

Вот контроллеры для страниц:

1. welcome.php:

   - Created by JetBrains PhpStorm.
   - User: GiBSON
   - Date: 18.04.12
   - Time: 23:50
     */

   class Controller_Welcome extends Controller_Site {

   ```
   public $template = 'main_page';
   protected $path, $cur_elem;

   public function action_index() {
       $page = ORM::factory('page')->root('main');
       $spec = ORM::factory('news')->get_last(2);
       $this->template->page = $page;
       $this->template->spec = $spec;
       $this->template->title = $page->title;
       $this->template->keywords = $page->keywords;
       $this->template->description = $page->description;
   }

   public function action_sitemap(){
       $this->auto_render = false;
       $exclude_ids = array(1);
       $sitemap = new sitemap('http://вашазащита66.рф');
       $sitemap->add_url('/');
       $structure = new Model_Page();
       $structure = $structure->where('id', 'NOT IN', $exclude_ids)->find_all();
       foreach ($structure as $item) {
           if (!$item->alias) continue;
           $url = $item->get_full_path($item->alias);
           $sitemap->add_url($url);
       }
       $sitemap->save();
   }
   ```

   }
2. special.php:

   - Created by PhpStorm.
   - User: GiBSON
   - Date: 09.08.13
   - Time: 16:37
     */

   class Controller_Special extends Controller_Site {
       public function action_index() {
           $alias = $this->request->param('alias');
           if (!$alias) {
               $this->_list();
           } else {
               $this->show($alias);
           }
       }

   ```
   private function _list() {
       $this->template->title = 'Спецпредложения юридической компании Ваша Защита';
       $this->template->name = 'Спецпредложения';
       $items = ORM::factory('news')->where('show', '=', 1)->order_by('date', 'desc')->find_all();
       $this->template->content = View::factory('special_list')->set('items', $items);
   }

   private function show($alias) {
       $item = ORM::factory('news')->where('alias', '=', $alias)
           ->where('show', '=', 1)->find();
       if (!$item->loaded()) {
           throw new HTTP_Exception_404('spec not found');
       }
       $this->template->title = $item->name;
       $this->template->name = $item->name;
       $this->template->content = $item->text;
   }
   ```

   }

3.ajax.php:

```
<?php
defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: GiBSON
 * Date: 09.09.13
 * Time: 17:07
 */

class Controller_Ajax extends Controller {

    public function action_question() {
        $mailer = new Mailer();
        $name = Arr::get($_POST, 'name');
        $question = Arr::get($_POST, 'question');
        $email = Arr::get($_POST, 'email');
        $emails = explode(';', Settings::get('pages_notify'));
        $emails = array_filter($emails, array('Swift_Validate', 'email'));
        $mailer->setFrom('mailer@vashazacshita66.ru');
        $mailer->setSubject('Вам был задан вопрос');
        $body = "Вам был отправлен вопрос." . $mailer->LE;
        $body .= 'Имя ' . $name . $mailer->LE;
        $body .= 'E-mail ' . $email . $mailer->LE;
        $body .= 'Вопрос ' . $question . $mailer->LE;
        $mailer->setBody($body);
        foreach ($emails as $mail) {
            $mailer->setTo($mail);
            $mailer->send();
        }
    }

    public function action_recall() {
        $mailer = new Mailer();
        $name = Arr::get($_POST, 'name');
        $phone = Arr::get($_POST, 'phone');
        $emails = explode(';', Settings::get('pages_notify'));
        $emails = array_filter($emails, array('Swift_Validate', 'email'));

        $mailer->setTo($emails);
        $mailer->setFrom('mailer@vashazacshita66.ru');
        $mailer->setSubject('Запрос на звонок');
        $body = "Вам был отправлен запрос." . $mailer->LE;
        $body .= 'Имя ' . $name . $mailer->LE;
        $body .= 'Телефон ' . $phone . $mailer->LE;
        $mailer->setBody($body);
        foreach ($emails as $mail) {
            $mailer->setTo($mail);
            $mailer->send();
        }
    }
```

4.ajax.php:

```
<?php
defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: GiBSON
 * Date: 09.09.13
 * Time: 17:07
 */

class Controller_Ajax extends Controller {

    public function action_question() {
        $mailer = new Mailer();
        $name = Arr::get($_POST, 'name');
        $question = Arr::get($_POST, 'question');
        $email = Arr::get($_POST, 'email');
        $emails = explode(';', Settings::get('pages_notify'));
        $emails = array_filter($emails, array('Swift_Validate', 'email'));
        $mailer->setFrom('mailer@vashazacshita66.ru');
        $mailer->setSubject('Вам был задан вопрос');
        $body = "Вам был отправлен вопрос." . $mailer->LE;
        $body .= 'Имя ' . $name . $mailer->LE;
        $body .= 'E-mail ' . $email . $mailer->LE;
        $body .= 'Вопрос ' . $question . $mailer->LE;
        $mailer->setBody($body);
        foreach ($emails as $mail) {
            $mailer->setTo($mail);
            $mailer->send();
        }
    }

    public function action_recall() {
        $mailer = new Mailer();
        $name = Arr::get($_POST, 'name');
        $phone = Arr::get($_POST, 'phone');
        $emails = explode(';', Settings::get('pages_notify'));
        $emails = array_filter($emails, array('Swift_Validate', 'email'));

        $mailer->setTo($emails);
        $mailer->setFrom('mailer@vashazacshita66.ru');
        $mailer->setSubject('Запрос на звонок');
        $body = "Вам был отправлен запрос." . $mailer->LE;
        $body .= 'Имя ' . $name . $mailer->LE;
        $body .= 'Телефон ' . $phone . $mailer->LE;
        $mailer->setBody($body);
        foreach ($emails as $mail) {
            $mailer->setTo($mail);
            $mailer->send();
        }
    }
}
```

5.content.php:

```
<?php
defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');
/**
 * Created by JetBrains PhpStorm.
 * User: GiBSON
 * Date: 18.04.12
 * Time: 23:50
 */

class Controller_Content extends Controller_Site {

    protected $path, $cur_elem;

    public function action_index() {
        $this->path = $this->request->param();
        $page = new Model_Page();
        $this->path_elems = $page->get_page($this->path);
        if ($this->path_elems === false) {
            throw new HTTP_Exception_404('Page not found');
        }
        if (is_array($this->path_elems) && !end($this->path_elems)->show) {
            throw new HTTP_Exception_404('Page not found');
        }

        $this->cur_elem = array_pop($this->path_elems);
        $this->template->content = $this->cur_elem->text;
        $this->template->name = $this->cur_elem->name;
        $this->template->title = $this->cur_elem->title;
        $this->template->keywords = $this->cur_elem->keywords;
        $this->template->description = $this->cur_elem->description;
    }

}
```